# Prove or disprove: "Zero-product" for limits at a point.

Tags: limits

I'm trying to prove/disprove the following theorem:

$$\forall f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}. \lim_{x \to x_0} (f\cdot g)(x) =0 \Rightarrow  \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)=0  \vee \lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)=0 $$

I see that it's true if there exists a finite limit at $x_0$ for f and g, which stems from limit arithmetic. However, I didn't manage to find a counterexample  or an $\epsilon  - \delta $ proof.

Hints? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}(f\cdot g)(x) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, just fixed. sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: take $f$ the characteristic function of the rationals, and $g$ of the irrationals, and $x_0=0$.

Comment: Excellent. I guess I'm slightly inexperianced with these pathological examples...